# Pundit - authorize not being called, but no error is being thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm using pundit for authorization. It's not working as expected, but when calling `authorize` no error is being thrown to say no method.

spec:

```
it "should let a user destroy their own picture" do
  sign_in(user2)
  expect do
    delete :destroy, { id: p1.id }
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end.to change { Picture.count }.by(-1)
end

it "should not let a user delete another user's picture" do
  sign_in(user2)
  expect do
    delete :destroy, { id: p1.id }
    expect(response.status).to eq(403)
  end.to change { Picture.count }.by(0)
end
```

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  include Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
  ...
end
```

PicturesController:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find_by_id(params[:id])
    authorize(@picture)
    @picture.destroy
    redirect_to pictures_path
  end
end
```

ApplicationPolicy

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

PicturePolicy

```
class PicturePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def destroy?
    @user&.id == @record&.user_id
  end
end
```

When I run my test with the `authorize(picture)` line, neither get destroyed, without it, both get destroyed. When adding some put statements inside of `PicturePolicy#destroy?`, they don't get shown. If I add a `ApplicationPolicy#destroy?`, it also doesn't seem to be called. However when I add `authorize(obj)` to my controller, nothing after that code is being run, neither policy#authorize is being run, but a 200 is being returned.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using a safe access `&.` in a version of ruby it doesn't exist in. Removing that fixed it.